# Merging graphics objects does not render text correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, system.drawing

I'm trying to solve a problem with a custom control ported from a VCL C++ application. The idea is that individual parts of the control are drawn first on a new Graphics object and then merged with the Graphics object from the control's paint method.

I've created a simplified example:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        private PictureBox pictureBox;

        public Form1()
        {
            pictureBox = new PictureBox();
            pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pictureBox.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox_Paint);

            ClientSize = new Size(100, 50);
            Controls.Add(pictureBox);
        }

        private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

            Font font = new Font(pictureBox.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
            graphics.DrawString("simple test", font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code results in the text being drawn too thick:

[image]

When i modify the code to draw the text directly to the Graphics object of the PictureBox i get the correct result:

[image]

This problem only occurs with text rendering. Lines and other shapes are rendered correctly. Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you forgot to initialize the bitmap pixels.  By default they are Color.Transparent, which is black with an alpha of 0.  This goes wrong when you draw anti-aliased text into the bitmap, the aliasing algorithm will draw pixels that blend from the foreground (black) to the background (also black).  Blobby letters that are not anti-aliased is the result.

This is not a problem in the 2nd screenshot because the background pixels were drawn to battleship gray by the default Form.OnPaintBackground() method.  Simply add the Graphics.Clear() method to fix your problem:

```
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height)) {
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
        graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);                // <== NOTE: added
        graphics.DrawString("simple test", pictureBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
}
```

With *using* statements added to prevent your program from crashing when the garbage collector doesn't run often enough.